# UITableView's separators and header strange behavior iOS9 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I have some `UITableView` with `UILabel` in it's header. It looks perfect on iPhone:
[Screenshot of iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl1uC.png)

But on iPad I show this view in a master of `UISplitViewController` and my header has no text! That's not all the problem. Look at cell separators. Why do they start at the middle of view?
[Screenshot of iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZkNP.png)

Constraints for label:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, PCHeaderHeight)];

    [headerView addSubview:oldMessages];

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"label": oldMessages};
    [headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[label]-|"
                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:views]];
    [headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[label]-|"
                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:views]];
```

Comment: What are the constraints for your `UILabel`?

Comment: View Debugger shows all on it's right places, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is only in the simulator, Test a device is likely that this standard.(Personal Experience)

Comment: I tried to run this from Xcode on connected iPad, and there was a same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my mistake was that I missed `[super viewWillAppear]` in my view controller inherited from `UISplitViewController`.
Thanks.